# Given a certain Pearson correlation between A and B, can I extimate the probability that two groups with different mean A will have different mean B?

Tags: correlation, chi-squared-test, mean, pearson-r

let's say I look for the correlation between variables A and B and find it to be high (say 0.80), eg height and weight of people. Can I then expect that if I encounter two populations with different mean A1 and A2 (height) then B (weight)  has got to be different? Can this be measured (such as how different the two means need to be, given the coefficient, to expect with a certain probability that this is the case)?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If correlation between A and B is universal, across all populations, and you find that the mean of A1 and A2 are significantly different, then yes, you can expect that B1 is different from B2.

You are asking how different mean of A1 and A2 must be for you to know if they are significantly different, and this is dependent on the sample size of A1 and A2. You can perform a simple t-test to test the difference of means.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry maybe I didn't explain well. I don't mean how do I find out that A1 and A2 are sign. different. I mean once I find that, is there a measure of certainty that B1 and B2 will therefore also be different?